# JSON - Array of Objects within a Array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

I am having trouble to parse a JSON string. The JSON is given below:

```
[
  {
    "firstname": "firstname",
    "lastname": "lastname",
    "address": "address",
    "images": [
      {
        "image": {          
          "url": "url",
          "id": "id"
        }
      },
      {
        "image": {
          "url": "url",
          "id": "id"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "firstname": "firstname",
    "lastname": "lastname",
    "address": "address",
    "images": [
      {
        "image": {          
          "url": "url",
          "id": "id"
        }
      },
      {
        "image": {
          "url": "url",
          "id": "id"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have defined the required Beans as:
Person.java

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 38L;

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String address;
    private Image[] images;

    public Person() {

    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Image[] getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(Image[] images) {
        this.images = images;
    }
}
```

Image.java:

```
public class Image implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 39L;

    private String url;
    private String id;

    public Image() {

    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }       
}
```

Now I am parsing the JSON string as:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
Person[] persons = (Person[])gson.fromJson(jsonString, Person[].class);
```

Now if I print

```
System.out.println(persons[0].getFirstname());
System.out.println(persons[0].getLastname());
System.out.println(persons[0].getAddress());
```

it is printing the corresponding values. Also:

```
persons[0].getImages() is not null;
persons[0].getImages()[0] is not null;
```

but

```
persons[0].getImages()[0].getUrl() is null;
persons[0].getImages()[0].getId() is null;
```

I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong? Is there any mistake I made in defining the beans?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you shouldn't specify name of object inside the array. Replace

```
"image": {          
    "url": "url",
    "id": "id"
}
```

with simply

```
{          
    "url": "url",
    "id": "id"
}
```

In case you want to parse specified JSON String you should have differen Object structure:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 38L;

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String address;
    private Foo[] images;
}

public class Foo{
    private Image image;
}
public class Image implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 39L;

    private String url;
    private String id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that probably you want your JSON to look more like

```
[
  {
    "firstname": "firstname",
    "lastname": "lastname",
    "address": "address",
    "images": [   
      {
          "url": "url",
          "id": "id"
      }...
```

That is, it might be getting confused by the "image" tag within the "images" array

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am not generating the JSON, I am parsing it. So the problem is in bean definition! How can I correct it?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'd think that you need to have an "image" object within your "image" object, but that's really messy and confusing design. Hopefully someone else with more experience can show you a good way around this, but my solution would probably be to just go through the work of using a more granular parser; e.g. [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

Or, of course, you could manually process the jsonstring before parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need another object to contain the image such that

```
class Image {
   String image; Info info;
}

class Info {
  String url, String id;
}
```